# Can RSpec stubbed method return different values in sequence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, stub

I have a model Family with a method `location` which merges the `location` outputs of other objects, Members. (Members are associated with families, but that's not important here.)

For example, given

- member_1 has `location` == 'San Diego (traveling, returns 15 May)'
- member_2 has `location` == 'San Diego'

Family.location might return 'San Diego (member_1 traveling, returns 15 May)' The specifics are unimportant.

To simplify the testing of Family.location, I want to stub Member.location. However, I need it to return two different (specified) values as in the example above. Ideally, these would be based on an attribute of `member`, but simply returning different values in a sequence would be OK. Is there a way to do this in RSpec?

It's possible to override the Member.location method within each test example, such as

```
it "when residence is the same" do 
  class Member
    def location
      return {:residence=>'Home', :work=>'his_work'} if self.male?
      return {:residence=>'Home', :work=>'her_work'}
    end
  end
  @family.location[:residence].should == 'Home'
end
```

but I doubt this is good practice. In any case, when RSpec is running a series of examples it doesn't restore the original class, so this kind of override "poisons" subsequent examples.

So, is there a way to have a stubbed method return different, specified values on each call?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can stub a method to return different values each time it's called;

```
allow(@family).to receive(:location).and_return('first', 'second', 'other')
```

So the first time you call `@family.location` it will return 'first', the second time it will return 'second', and all subsequent times you call it, it will return 'other'.

Comment: Thanks @idlefingers !  What if you want to return large numbers of values though?

Comment: @La-comadreja say you have a long array of strings called `my_big_array`, you could do `allow(@family).to receive(:location).and_return(*my_big_array)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: What about raising an error the first time something is called and the returning a value the second time?

Comment: @JamesKlein I'm trying to do the same. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I used the suggestion mentioned [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/1114#issuecomment-241925251), which is essentially to use a block and a counter that you increment yourself.

Comment: Can it raise error the first time and return something the next time?

Comment: Dude, I've been doing Ruby for almost a decade and I didn't know this!

Answer (score 21):

RSpec 3 syntax:

```
allow(@family).to receive(:location).and_return("abcdefg", "bcdefgh")
```

Answer (score 14):

The accepted solution should only be used if you have a specific number of calls and need a specific sequence of data. But **what if you don't know the number of calls that will be made, or don't care about the order of data** only that it's something different each time? As OP said:

> simply returning different values in a sequence would be OK

The issue with `and_return` is that the return value is memoized. Meaning even if you'd return something dynamic you'll always get the same.

E.g.

```
allow(mock).to receive(:method).and_return(SecureRandom.hex)
mock.method # => 7c01419e102238c6c1bd6cc5a1e25e1b
mock.method # => 7c01419e102238c6c1bd6cc5a1e25e1b
```

Or a practical example would be using factories and getting the same IDs:

```
allow(Person).to receive(:create).and_return(build_stubbed(:person))
Person.create # => Person(id: 1)
Person.create # => Person(id: 1)
```

**In these cases you can stub the method body to have the code executed every time:**

```
allow(Member).to receive(:location) do
  { residence: Faker::Address.city }
end
Member.location # => { residence: 'New York' }
Member.location # => { residence: 'Budapest' }
```

Note that you have no access to the Member object via `self` in this context but can use variables from the testing context.

E.g.

```
member = build(:member)
allow(member).to receive(:location) do
  { residence: Faker::Address.city, work: member.male? 'his_work' : 'her_work' }
end
```

Comment: If you need to call allow with receive multiple times, pass a block instead of using "and_return()"

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you want to use the old syntax, you can still:

```
@family.stub(:location).and_return('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the solution outline here above but it does not work for my. I solved the problem by  stubbing with a substitute implementation.

Something like:

```
@family.stub(:location) { rand.to_s }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that I had multiple calls to a method and not always in the same order. In that case, I'd recommend using `.with`, to distinguish between instances, using the method's arguments.

So for example, this could be your "default" returning value:

```
allow(@family).to receive(:location).and_return('her_work')
```

but then, if location receives an argument like "male", you can add:

```
allow(@family).to receive(:location).with("male").and_return('his_work')
```

There are lots of different matching argument types that can be used with `.with`:

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments